# Can I visualize mean values for "another variable" for boxes in a box plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data, showing percentage of credits taken given different high school backgrounds:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
ggplot(fulldata,aes(x=fct_reorder(gymnasiegrov, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y=PERC_CREDIT))+geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()
```

I've been asked to add information on the mean age for each group/boxplot, since age can be a confounding variable.

Can this actually be done (with geom_text or something similar) or do I have to visualize that information in another way?

The mean age values should be showcased in connecton witih each group. They don't have to be superimposed on the plot. It would be perfectly acceptable to showcase the values beside it (if I can convince R markdown to show a table and a boxplot on the same page for instance), as long as they're in the correct order.

Small excerpt of data:

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776), class = "Date"), PERC_CREDIT = c(56.2962962962963, 
69.6296296296296, 0, 1.48148148148148, 60, 0), gymnasiegrov = structure(c(11L, 
9L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 4L), .Label = c("medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", 
"Hotell- och Restaurang", "komvux", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
"naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
"bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
"Oklart", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
"estetiska programmet", "friskoleprogram", "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), ålder = structure(c(20, 20, 
19, 32, 27, 26), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(17776, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:6)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Large excerpt of data:

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776), class = "Date"), 
    PERC_CREDIT = c(56.2962962962963, 69.6296296296296, 0, 1.48148148148148, 
    60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16.2962962962963, 1.48148148148148, 1.48148148148148, 
    0, 93.3333333333333, 45.1851851851852, 0, 0, 93.3333333333333, 
    0, 71.1111111111111, 5.18518518518519, 65.1851851851852, 
    69.6296296296296, 1.48148148148148, 1.48148148148148, 86.6666666666667, 
    84.4444444444444, 97.037037037037, 85.1851851851852, 83.7037037037037, 
    0, 80, 57.037037037037, 61.4814814814815, 0, 80.7407407407407, 
    80, 0, 0, 84.4444444444444, 34.8148148148148, 1.48148148148148, 
    44.4444444444444, 0, 70.3703703703704, 0, 76.2962962962963, 
    14.0740740740741, 94.8148148148148, 86.6666666666667, 0, 
    80, 94.0740740740741, 95.5555555555556, 100, 84.4444444444444, 
    79.2592592592593, 28.1481481481481, 94.0740740740741, 83.7037037037037, 
    55.5555555555556, 95.5555555555556, 0, 0, 14.0740740740741, 
    22.962962962963, 0, 47.4074074074074, 50.3703703703704, 0, 
    51.8518518518518, 84.4444444444444, 88.1481481481482, 82.2222222222222, 
    45.9259259259259, 37.7777777777778, 84.4444444444444, 0, 
    0, 0, 86.6666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 76.2962962962963, 
    25.9259259259259, 34.0740740740741, 0, 0, 0, 8.88888888888889, 
    51.8518518518518, 102.222222222222, 94.0740740740741, 86.6666666666667, 
    33.3333333333333, 80, 0, 1.48148148148148, 48.8888888888889, 
    0, 28.1481481481481, 0, 82.2222222222222, 0, 0, 84.4444444444444, 
    97.7777777777778, 78.5185185185185, 95.5555555555556, 70.3703703703704, 
    1.48148148148148, 27.4074074074074, 80.7407407407407, 82.962962962963, 
    97.7777777777778, 94.0740740740741, 72.5925925925926, 82.962962962963, 
    95.5555555555556, 0, 82.962962962963, 0, 82.2222222222222, 
    70.3703703703704, 97.7777777777778, 1.48148148148148, 20, 
    82.962962962963, 0, 68.8888888888889, 60.7407407407407, 97.7777777777778, 
    25.9259259259259, 46.6666666666667, 0, 84.4444444444444, 
    69.6296296296296, 82.2222222222222, 100, 0, 82.2222222222222, 
    1.48148148148148, 80, 85.9259259259259, 95.5555555555556, 
    77.7777777777778, 97.7777777777778, 97.7777777777778, 53.3333333333333, 
    33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 12.5925925925926, 23.7037037037037, 
    77.7777777777778, 77.7777777777778), gymnasiegrov = structure(c(11L, 
    9L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 
    12L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 14L, 12L, 7L, 
    8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 7L, 
    2L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 
    9L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 
    7L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    11L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 7L, 
    6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 
    7L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 15L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 
    7L, 5L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 
    11L, 8L, 4L, 13L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L), .Label = c("medieprogrammet/medieproduktion", "Hotell- och Restaurang", 
    "komvux", "teknikprogrammet", "specialutformat program", 
    "naturvetenskapliga programmet", "ekonomiprogrammet/ ekonomi", 
    "bygg, el, fordon, hantverk, sjöfart, industriteknik", "ekonomiprogrammet/ juridik", 
    "Oklart", "samhällsvetenskapliga programmet", "Handels- och administrationsprogrammet", 
    "estetiska programmet", "friskoleprogram", "samhälls- och ekonomiprogrammet"
    ), class = c("ordered", "factor")), ålder = structure(c(20, 
    20, 19, 32, 27, 26, 23, 22, 20, 20, 25, 25, 23, 22, 19, 26, 
    24, 26, 23, 20, 25, 25, 24, 21, 19, 26, 24, 24, 23, 22, 21, 
    20, 20, 29, 27, 21, 20, 20, 20, 25, 24, 19, 39, 34, 29, 22, 
    20, 33, 25, 19, 22, 21, 30, 24, 22, 21, 19, 22, 25, 19, 26, 
    24, 29, 20, 22, 19, 19, 20, 30, 20, 21, 19, 19, 19, 22, 21, 
    19, 19, 23, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 24, 24, 33, 19, 19, 21, 24, 
    19, 23, 33, 21, 27, 23, 20, 19, 20, 19, 22, 21, 19, 21, 19, 
    21, 19, 20, 19, 19, 20, 19, 21, 22, 19, 20, 25, 19, 22, 19, 
    19, 19, 25, 23, 20, 19, 26, 19, 21, 19, 20, 25, 20, 19, 23, 
    19, 28, 19, 19, 19, 32, 20, 23, 21, 19, 20, 47, 39, 27, 26, 
    25, 24, 21), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-154L), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(17776, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:154)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: your data does not contain the column `PERC_CREDIT`. Please try to produce a reprex. Also maybe just condense your code, using an inbuilt data set.   http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/  http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/

Comment: My apologies, I was tired when I posted that question. By repex I guess you mean "reproducible example". It's unclear to me if that phrase have an implicit meaning on stack exchange but just in case, I'm posting the data I used to calculate the first plot. 

If there's anything more I can do to help please let me know.

Comment: yes "reprex" is kind of a common term here. I have removed my downvote although the code is still massively abundant - please try to reduce your data to the most relevant in future questions. Also, I did not see your reply until now - next time if you add @tjebo to the comment I will be notified. I don't need to add this to my comment here because the "post owner" (here: you) will be notified in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply plot the mean age next to your plot.

```
library(ggpubr) # for ggarrange

fulldata$age <- as.numeric(fulldata$ålder)

# your plot
g1 <- ggplot(fulldata,aes(x=fct_reorder(gymnasiegrov, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y = PERC_CREDIT)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()

# age mean plot 
g2 <- ggplot(fulldata) + stat_summary(aes(x = fct_reorder(gymnasiegrov, PERC_CREDIT, .fun = median,na.rm=T), y = age), 
                                     fun.data = "mean_se") + coord_flip() + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), # remove y axis labels since the're long
        axis.title.y = element_blank())# and the same as the first.

ggarrange(g1, g2, ncol=2, widths = c(.65,.35))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! Is there anyway I can multiply the standard error with 1.96 so I can get something approaching a confidence interval?

Comment: Or is the standard error already multiplied by two, so we see 1*(standard error) on each side of the mean?

Comment: You can specify what you want as descriptive functions in the `stat_summary()` function. Use the `fun.ymin` and `fun.ymax` arguments to change what the segments correspond to.